# True or False regarding the behavior of limits of $f'(x)$ given $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives, monotone-functions

Suppose we have a function $f:(0,\infty) \to (0,1)$ with $f'(x) < 0, f''(x) > 0$, and the two limits:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 1\\
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0
\end{align}

Then is this statement true?

$\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x)$ exists and is negative and not equal to negative infinity.

I understand that the first part must be true as f'(x) is monotone, but I'm not too sure about the second part.

Any function that I can think of ($\frac{1}{1+x}$, etc.) seem to work, and it sounds intuitively true since $f$ is approaching 0, but can't seem to be able to prove it.

Comment: No, take $f(x)=e^{-x}$.

Comment: But $e^{-x}$ works doesn't it? $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{d}{dx} e^{-x} = -1$

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=f'(x)$, so we are given $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=L$, and$~g(x)<0, g'(x)>0,\forall x>0$

Assume $L=0$, and pick any point $x_0>0$, where $g(x_0)=-h<0$

Since $L=0, \Rightarrow \exists \delta<x_0,~0<|x-0|<\delta\Rightarrow|g(x)-0|<h/2\Rightarrow g(x)>-h/2$

So we have $x<x_0$ but $g(x)>g(x_0)$, which conflicts with $g'(x)>0,~\forall x>0$

Similarly we can prove if $L>0$ it also gives contradictions. Therefore, $L<0$.

But $L$ could be $-\infty$, for example, you can construct a function such that $f(x)\to1-\sqrt{x}$ when $x$ is close to $0^+$ and  $f(x)\to e^{-x}$, when $x\to \infty$.

Comment: But $-\sqrt{x}$ approaches -$\infty$ so it doesn't meet my second limit requirement doesn't it?

Comment: OK, I edited it.

Comment: Could you elaborate that last part? How would you make a differentiable function that fits that criteria?